# How to use <p> tag in res.write() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post

I use this code to show a response of an API request and wanted to seperate my two res.write() parts.

I tried a paragraph but VS is crying :)

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var crypto = req.body.crypto;
  var fiat = req.body.fiat;

  var baseUrl = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/";
  var url = baseUrl + crypto + fiat;

  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var price = data.last;
    var currentDate = data.display_timestamp;
    res.write("<p>date:  " + currentDate</p>);
    res.write(
      "Result: Price of " + crypto + " in " + fiat + " is " + price + "."
    );
    res.send();
  });
});
```

Comment: ```res.write("<p>date:  " + currentDate + "</p>");```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo in this line:

```
res.write("<p>date:  " + currentDate</p>);
```

It should be:

```
res.write("<p>date:  " + currentDate + "</p>");
```

In the first version, it is having the closing tag as plain javascript, which is wrong. Should be inside a string (as you do with the opening tag).

Comment: sure. if you vote my question one up that will help me also. cu